# Unable to set the counter when clicking on the current button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have 5 steps with Previous, Current & Next buttons and counter below it. I am able to move forward and backward with the help of Previous, Current & Next buttons. But, I am facing problem in the counter. I am considering Step-3 is current step. When I am clicking on Current button, I am able to come back to step-3 but the counter is not coming to 3 instead it is taking the last step number. Please check the code and help me with the issue.

```js
var current = 1,
          current_step, next_step, steps;
        steps = $("fieldset").length;
        var fieldset_count = steps.current;
        if (current == '1') {
          // $('#first-step a').add('disabled');
          $('#first-step a.previous').prop('disabled', true);
        };
        if ($('fieldset').hasClass('last-step')) {
          $('#last-step a.next').prop('disabled', true);
        }


        $(".next").on("click", function () {
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $(this).parent("fieldset").next();
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          $('.counter-step').html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
          });

        });

        $(".previous").on("click", function () {
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $(this).parent("fieldset").prev();
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          $('.counter-step').html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 - 1
          });
        });

        // Current button functionality
        $(".current").on("click",function(){
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $("#current-step");
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          var current_counter = $(this).parent("fieldset").attr('value');
          $('.counter-step').text(current_counter);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/icofont/icofont.min.css">

</head>
<style>
  .container fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <fieldset id="first-step" value="1">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-1</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="2">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-2</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="3" id="current-step">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-3</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="4" >
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-4</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="last-step" id="last-step" value="4">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-5</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <p>Viewing Step <span class="counter-step">1</span> of <span class="final-step">23</span></p>
  </div>






    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current button you are clicking is within the active fieldset that you are currently on, NOT the value='3' fieldset. The 'this' context for the button that is being clicked is pulling the parent of the fieldset that is visible *before* being hidden, not the fieldset that shows afterwards.

Try passing `next_step.attr('value')` instead of `$(this).parent("fieldset").attr('value')`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the final code.

```js
var current = 1,
          current_step, next_step, steps;
        steps = $("fieldset").length;
        var fieldset_count = steps.current;
        if (current == '1') {
          // $('#first-step a').add('disabled');
          $('#first-step a.previous').prop('disabled', true);
        };
        if ($('fieldset').hasClass('last-step')) {
          $('#last-step a.next').prop('disabled', true);
        }


        $(".next").on("click", function () {
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $(this).parent("fieldset").next();
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          $('.counter-step').html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 + 1
          });

        });

        $(".previous").on("click", function () {
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $(this).parent("fieldset").prev();
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          $('.counter-step').html(function (i, val) {
            return val * 1 - 1
          });
        });

        // Current button functionality
        $(".current").on("click",function(){
          current_step = $(this).parent("fieldset");
          next_step = $("#current-step");
          next_step.show();
          current_step.hide();
          var current_counter = next_step.attr('value');
          $('.counter-step').text(current_counter);
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/icofont/icofont.min.css">

</head>
<style>
  .container fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
    display: none;
  }
</style>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <fieldset id="first-step" value="1">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-1</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="2">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-2</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="3" id="current-step">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-3</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset value="4" >
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-4</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="last-step" id="last-step" value="4">
      <h4 class="mb-3 header">Step-5</h4>
      <a type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-secondary" value="Previous">Previous</a>
      <a type="button" name="current" class="current btn btn-success" value="Current">Current</a>
      <a type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-primary" value="Next">Next</a>
    </fieldset>
    <p>Viewing Step <span class="counter-step">1</span> of <span class="final-step">23</span></p>
  </div>






    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.